# How to trigger SQLServer suggestion popupmenu

Tags: sql-server, sql-management-studio

I have a very big job to do on a very large SQLServer DB, with unusually large table names.

Having the popup menu suggesting the names of the tables and such, would really come in handy, but it doesn't trigger every time I type a letter, and I don't know the combinations of keys to trigger its appearance in order to trigger it myself.

[image]

I'm using Microsoft `SQL Server Management Studio version 11.0.2100.60`

Comment: Post a link to any images at a public sharing site like imgur.com, and someone here will embed them for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify Transact-SQL IntelliSense options:

On the Tools menu, click Options.

Expand Text Editor, expand Transact-SQL, and then click IntelliSense.

Clear the check boxes for the IntelliSense options that you do not want.

To change the script size at which IntelliSense features are disabled, select a size from the Maximum script size list.

To change the casing applied to function names in completion lists, select a casing specification from the Casing for built-in function names list.

Click OK.

[image]

**Note**
To edit these setting:
Edit -> IntelliSense 
The command is called `Complete Word` and I believe the default setting is Cntrl+RightArrow.

( As per OPs comments )

**Also** alias tables to get specific columns for that table, see image below.

[image]

Comment: I already had the options that you described. And still the appearance of the popup was uneven. So i made a little research on my on: by going to Edit -> IntelliSense i've seen the shortcut that actually triggers the popup appearance. The command is called 'Complete Word' and i believe the default setting is Cntrl+RightArrow. This works for me, all the time. Confirm to me that this works for you too, so you can edit your post and i can accept it

Comment: @BabaNew glad you found it out, I've included as an edit, & welcome to SU uperUser

Answer (score 2):

You should configure IntelliSense in SQL Server Management Studio. IntelliSense Complete Word option types the rest of a variable, command, or function name once you have entered enough characters to uniquely identify the term.